# Directory listing for s3 prefix with presigned urls

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Is it possible to provide a directory listing of a portion of a bucket by prefix (e.g. a listing for /portionprefix/) by providing 3rd parties with presigned urls without own code to create the view?

My idea was that the customer would provide a token and the prefix to aws lambda, which would return an URL of some sort upon successful authorization where the customer would get a file browser or directory listing.

I was wondering if amazon already provides something for that out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 pre-signed URLs are for objects so you can't do this natively.

You could write a Lambda function that, given an S3 prefix and appropriate credentials, enumerated the S3 objects with that prefix and returned them as a list.

Another option you might consider is for a Lambda function to enumerate the S3 objects with the given prefix and then write that list of objects to a text file in S3, and then return a pre-signed URL for that text file to the customer. The customer could then retrieve the text file in a single operation and its contents would be the list of objects.